# How to use ZenPen in a web site as rich text editor?

Tags: richtextbox, rich-text-editor, zenpen

I am developing a new web site and i was looking for a rich text editor which will be help users to write heavy texts easily. Then i discovered amazing app [ZenPen](http://www.zenpen.io/).
But as i undestood it is designed as a standalone app instead of using in a web site.

There is no html form support or form elements even. So i am trying to get texts from `<header>` or `<article>` tags via jQuery. But i wonder is there another way to achieve this.

If i couldn't achieve this my other alternatives are [grande.js](http://mattduvall.com/grande.js/) or [medium.js](http://jakiestfu.github.io/Medium.js/docs/)

Answer (score 0):

Zenpen is not intended to be used as library but standalone product (I wish it could serve both purposes).

> ZenPen is a stand alone product, and thats how I'd like to maintain it.

tholman (Zenpen's maintainer)

Source https://github.com/tholman/zenpen/issues/102